# Google Sheets: Can't sort correctly with thousand separator

Tags: google-sheets

I'm making a list to compare who's leading the "most watched films" race, using `IMPORTXML()` to scrap information from Letterboxd and `SORT()`.

The thing is that Letterboxd uses commas as thousand separator, and `SORT()` thinks it is a decimal separator. Because of this, it puts the highest number down below the list when sorted. I tried using the `=SUBSTITUTE()` function (`=SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(A3; "//*[@id='profile-header']/div/div[4]/div[1]/h4[1]/a/span[1]"); ","; ".")`) for changing commas to dots (or even removing commas) and it doesn't work. `=SORT()` (`=sort(D3:E21; 2; FALSE)`) sorts not by highest number, it does something strange like this: `95, 9, 87, 82, 7, (...) 1302, 12`

What can I do? Changing locale does not work.

Comment: SUBSTITUTE is changing numbers to strings. Try `1*SUBSTITUTE( )`, removing the commas altogether. This should convert them back to numbers. If this doesn't give the desired result. share a link to the sheet (or a copy of it), as that will be the only way to test anything further.

Comment: what is the url you wrote in A3?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User six times.

Answer (score 0):

Curiosity is a dangerous thing. @Daniele asked *what is the url you wrote in A3?* and I thought, that's a good question cause the xpath and the URL kind-of go together. So I got carried away and this is the result.

**Note:** the results are formulas based on the original `IMPORTXML`. At some stage, one might wish to `Copy, Paste special, Values only` to convert any given result to a value.

**Some variables**

[image: variables]

---

**ImportXML**

Cell A7: `=transpose(importxml(B1;B2))`

This generates the following data (or at least this snapshot of the first 20 values). Note: this formula uses a semi-colon separator because that's what the OP uses.

[image: importxml]

BTW, since it is a list, you could probably/possibly (warning: untested assertion) use `IMPORTHTML()` (along with the right query and index).

---

**Results**

The results are broken into data elements; you could combine these into just four formula (Score, Name, Year and Rating) if you were so inclined.

- Length of the imported string: `=arrayformula(len(A7:A106))`
- Position/location of the decimal point: `=arrayformula(search($B$3;A7:A106))`
- Position/location of the first star (★): `=arrayformula(search($B$4;A7:A106))`
- Number of Stars: `=arrayformula((LEN(A7:A106)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A7:A106;$B$4;)))/LEN($B$4))`
- Number of 'Halfs' (½): `=arrayformula((LEN(A7:A106)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A7:A106;$B$5;)))/LEN($B$5))`
- Score (out of 100): `=arrayformula(value(left(A7:A106;D7:D106-1)))`
- Title/Name : `=arrayformula(if(iserr(E7:E106);mid(A7:A106;D7:D106+1;C7:C106-D7:D106-5-1);mid(A7:A106;D7:D106+1;E7:E106-D7:D106-1-6)))`
- Year: `=arrayformula(if(iserr(E7:E106);right(trim(A7:A106);4);mid(A7:A106;E7:E106-5;4)))`
- Rating: `=arrayformula(if(F7:F106=0;"";rept($B$4;F7:F106))&if(G7:G106=0;"";rept($B$5;G7:G106)))`

[image: results]

Comment: very good @Tedinoz. I had come to something similar too ... but I couldn't find WHERE the number with the comma was!
So I decided to ask the "correct" URL

Comment: (there isn't an id='profile-header' in mine and your URL's XML)

Comment: ...by the way there are 500 movie titles distributed in 5 pages ... how can they be caught with a single IMPORTXML ??

Comment: Regarding 500 titles, Obviously the easiest thing would be to have a single url, but one doesn't jump off the page (excuse the pun), so I guess one would use a browser to advance to the next page, create a new import and so on  times five. I _do_ note that there is an API (though in private beta), and also that [If you require your account data in machine-readable form we have import and export options, and every account has an RSS feed of new diary entries and lists.](https://letterboxd.com/api-beta/). But that's for someone else (with an account, no less!) to pursue.

Comment: _(there isn't an id='profile-header' in mine and your URL's XML)_ I don't know what to say. I just used the xpath that Google browser Dev Tools gave me, though I did choose the "List" view (as opposed to the "Grid" view). I've done the `IMPORTHTML` version as well - check my second answer.

Comment: @Daniele Oops. Forgot to reference you in my previous comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133896/discussion-between-daniele-and-tedinoz).

Answer (score 0):

**The IMPORTHTML version**

I mentioned in my other answer that the data could be obtained using `importhtml`. Well...

**Note:** Again, the results are formulas based on the original `IMPORTHTML` formula. At some stage, one might wish to `Copy, Paste special, Values only` to convert any given result to a value.

**Some variables**

[image: variables]

Note that this version doesn't search for the star ("★") or half ("½") characters.    This is because the format generated by `importhtml` is completely different to the `importxml` format.

**IMPORTXTML Format** >
[image: html format]

Records with a rating (such as 'Guardians of the Galaxy') include 2 (two) carriage returns; records without a rating (such as 'Avengers: Infinity War') don't have any carriage returns.

So the spade character ('♠️') is used (`substitute`) to identify those records with a rating and those without a rating.

---

**ImportHTML**

Cell A6: `=arrayformula(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(importhtml($B$1;"list";14);char(10);"";1);char(10);"♠️";1))`

This generates the following. Note: again this formula uses a semi-colon separator because that's what the OP uses.

[image: results]

---

**Results**

The results are broken into data elements (similar to the `IMPORTXML` results). But this time, I've built single formulas for the 'Score', 'Name', 'Year' and 'Rating' and I'll show just those.

- Score (out of 100): `=arrayformula(value(left(A6:A105;search($B$2;A6:A105)-1)))`
- Title/Name : `=arrayformula(if(iserr(search($B$3;A6:A105));mid(A6:A105;search($B$2;A6:A105)+1;len(A6:A105)-search($B$2;A6:A105)-4);mid(A6:A105;search($B$2;A6:A105)+1;search($B$3;A6:A105)-search($B$2;A6:A105)-1-4)))`
- Year: `=arrayformula(if(iserr(search($B$3;A6:A105));right(A6:A105;4);mid(A6:A105;search($B$3;A6:A105)-4;4)))`
- Rating: `=arrayformula(if(iserr(search($B$3;A6:A105));"";mid(A6:A105;search($B$3;A6:A105)+1;len(A6:A105)-search($B$3;A6:A105))))`